# slice the middle of a dynamically generated string in Django

Tags: django, django-template-filters

Is there a way (Using Django filters or any other language) to find and slice certain parts of a dynamically generated string? I have tried the slice method and the truncate method

{{variable|slice:"130:-60"}} or
{{variable|truncatechars:255 }}

but neither of those methods work exactly right..... I am working on weather alerts (provided by the National Weather Service) and each alert comes with a unique ID on the front and (sometimes) on the back too.

The unique ID #'s and length vary between 60 and 130 characters and the ID at the end is longitude and latitude but it's only included about 1/2 the time.

So I am looking for / working on code to "sniff out" and remove the unique ID's and to only provide the text for the user to see.

What is the proper method to do this?

Here is an example of an alert:

INC077-437-75584393-/09584738.EGY/W.0027//KT.0215401321/ 1100 AM CDT WED MAY13 2015 THE FLOODING WILL CONTINUE FOR THE MISSISSIPPI RIVER NEAR ORLANDO FLORIDA. *FROM THIS EVENING TO THE END OF TIME* AT 600 AM WEDNESDAY THE STAGE WAS 30.5 FEET. *FLOOD STAGE IS 30.6 FEET* IMPACT BY TONIGHT AT 1000 PM SOME WATER BEGINS TO FILL SOME DITCHES. && LAT...LON 4125 5845 5458 6548 8964 5124 1234 8706 $$

and with code (where I call the variable) I want it to be:

1100 AM CDT WED MAY13 2015 THE FLOODING WILL CONTINUE FOR THE MISSISSIPPI RIVER NEAR ORLANDO FLORIDA. *FROM THIS EVENING TO THE END OF TIME* AT 600 AM WEDNESDAY THE STAGE WAS 30.5 FEET. *FLOOD STAGE IS 30.6 FEET* IMPACT BY TONIGHT AT 1000 PM SOME WATER BEGINS TO FILL SOME DITCHES.

but I can't cut or truncate because the length of every weather alert is different and each unique ID is a different # and a different length.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Logic goes to the view, presentation goes to the template. Are you sure what you want is just presentation? If not, couldn't you send it to the view or create a template tag for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom method to your model such as :

```
class Weather(models.Model):
    alert = models.TextField()

    @property
    def get_id(self):
        return self.alert.split('/')[-1]
```

And in your template :

```
<p>{{ weather.get_id }}</p>
```

You can also create a custom template filter :

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='get_id')
def get_id(value):
    return value.split('/')[-1]
```

And use it in your template this way :

```
<p>{{ weather|get_id }}</p>
```